# Allow access to more than one page in PHP/Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to allow access to two areas. Signup and Signin within Woocommerce. If there user is not logged in they are redirected to the accounts page to select to either signup or login. But i want the signup on a seperate page or link within myaccount/signup

```
    add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {

    if( ( !is_page('accounts', 'signup') ) ) {

        if (!is_user_logged_in() ) {
            wp_redirect( site_url( '/accounts' ) );        // redirect all...
            exit();
        }

    }

});
```

Is there something i am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this the correct way to do this, but it worked for me. I am no expert so take this example with a grain of salt.

If will force a login if the user goes to any other page than signup or accounts/login.

```
    // Redirect to accounts login page, if user is not logged in.
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {

    if( ( !is_page('accounts') && !is_page('signup') ) ) {

        if (!is_user_logged_in() ) {
            wp_redirect( site_url( '/accounts' ) );        // redirect all...
            exit();
        }

    }

});
```